# Jest mock react context

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-context, react-testing-library

I need some help understanding how one can test an application using `React` `Context`.

Here's my sample setup.

**context.js**

```
import React from 'react'

export const AppContext = React.createContext()
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react'

import MyComponent from './MyComponent'
import {AppContext} from './context'

const App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    items: []
  }

  handleItemAdd = newItem => {
    const {items} = this.state
    items.push(newItem)
    this.setState(items)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <AppContext.Provider value={{
        addItem: this.handleItemAdd
      }}>
        <MyComponent />
      </AppContext.Provider>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

**MyComponent.js**

```
import React from 'react'

import {AppContext} from './context'

const MyComponent extends React.Component {    
  render() {
    return (
      <AppContext.Consumer>
        {addItem => 
          <button onClick={() => addItem('new item')}>
            Click me
          </button>
        }
      </AppContext.Consumer>
    )
  }
}

export default MyComponent
```

This is a simplified example. Imagine that there are more layers between `App` and `MyComponent`, hence the use of `React` `Context`.

And here's my test file for `MyComponent`.

**MyComponent.test.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import {render, fireEvent} from 'react-testing-library'

test('component handles button click', () => {
  const {getByText} = render(
    <MyComponent />
  )
  const button = getByText('Click me')
  fireEvent.click(button)
  expect...?
}
```

The thing is, `AppContext.Consumer` is part of the implementation of `MyComponent`, so in this test I don't have direct access to it. How do I mock `AppContext.Consumer` so I am actually able to verify that clicking a button fires a function call?

I know that in theory I can test this by rendering `MyComponent` in my `App`, but I want to write a unit test for `MyComponent` only.

Comment: take a look into react-testing-library's docs: https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-context

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the example. So, is manually wrapping `MyComponent` in `AppContext.Provider` in each test the only way then?

Comment: it looks this way. enzyme's `shallow()` allows passing in context as an argument. but react-testing-library does not.

Comment: @skyboyer, Enzyme's `shallow` does not work with context in no way.

Answer (score 161, accepted):

You just render the context with your component.

```
const addItem = jest.fn()
render(
  <AppContext.Provider value={{ addItem }}>
    <MyComponent />
  </AppContext.Provider>
)
```

See [Mocking context with react-testing-library](https://www.polvara.me/posts/mocking-context-with-react-testing-library/)

Answer (score 7):

I want to add a complete test example by using the solution from @Giorgio.
Here we are testing that MyComponent is rendered and that its button will be clicked once.

**MyComponent.test.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { render, fireEvent } from 'react-testing-library'

test('component handles button click', () => {
  const addItem = jest.fn()
  render(
    <AppContext.Provider value={{ addItem }}>
      <MyComponent />
    </AppContext.Provider>
  )
  fireEvent.click(screen.getByText(/click me/))
  expect(addItem).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case there are any TypeScript users who can't get this solution to work, I want to add my test example for anyone in distress.

In my case I added a custom component wrapper that can be reused across the testing environment in your application. This can be handy if you are testing more than one component that is nested in the context that you wish to mock.

Also as a bonus I mocked the rxjs behavior subject in case anyone utilizes this library in their tests:

```
    // Create a mock BehaviorSubject instance
    class MockBehaviorSubject<T> extends BehaviorSubject<T> {
    constructor(initialValue: T) {
        super(initialValue);
    }

    // Override necessary methods
    getValue(): T {
        return this.getValue();
    }

    // Add any other required methods here
    // For example, you might need to add `next` method:
    // next(value: T): void {
    //   this.next(value);
    // }

    // Create a custom wrapper component to provide the mock context values
    export const MockAppProvider: React.FC<WithChildren> = ({ children }) => {
    // Define your mock context values here
    const id= 'test';

    // Create a mock BehaviorSubject instance
    const mockCreateObservablesCallbackSubject = new MockBehaviorSubject<
        TObservableEvent | undefined
    >(undefined);

    return (
        <AppProviderContext.Provider
            value={{
                id: mockCycleId,
                setId: jest.fn(),
                observables: undefined,
                setObservables: jest.fn(),
                createObservablesCallbackSubject: mockCreateObservablesCallbackSubject,
            }}
        >
            {children}
        </AppProviderContext.Provider>
    );
};

}
```