# How can I write unit test for api call with token using React, Jest and React-testing-library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, fetch-api

Here is the function that I wanna test, it takes a token and a description as props. Normally in React code, I can get token from useContext.

```
export const updateUserProfileAbout = async (
  token,
  description
) => {
  const dataUpdateTemplateDescriptionRes = await patchData(`me/`, token, {
    about:description,
  });
  const dataUpdateTemplateDescriptionJson  = await dataUpdateTemplateDescriptionRes.json();
  return dataUpdateTemplateDescriptionJson;
};
```

And here is my custom patchData function:

```
const patchData = async (urn, token, data = "") => {
  const headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token.access}`,
  };
  const body = data ? JSON.stringify(data) : null;
  let response;
  if (body) {
    response = await fetch(`${host}/api/${urn}`, {
      method: "PATCH",
      headers,
      body,
    });
  } else {
    response = await fetch(`${host}/api/${urn}`, {
      method: "PATCH",
      headers,
    });
  }
  if (!response.ok) throw new Error(response.status);
  return response;
};
```

Comment: Have you heard of Mock API (for example Mock Axios)?

Comment: @TanNguyen yes I did some research on mock API with Axios and Fetch API. However, I don't know how to mock API with token or using React ContextAPI in jest.

Comment: Try Googling with your keyword "ReactContext", "Jest", found some: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54292298/jest-mock-react-context

Answer (score 2):

You are right. You don't need the token. All you need to do for mocking the fetch is the following:

```
jest.spyOn(global, 'fetch').mockImplementationOnce(
jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()) as jest.Mock);
```

If you want to retrieve a specific object from a json response, you can use:

```
jest.spyOn(global, 'fetch').mockImplementationOnce(
jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ ok: true, json: () => Promise.resolve({ myObject }) })) as jest.Mock);
```

You can also reject it to trigger the error catch:

```
jest.spyOn(global, 'fetch').mockImplementationOnce(
jest.fn(() => Promise.reject()) as jest.Mock);
```

If you want to return something multiple times, change the `mockImplementationOnce` to whatever you need (maybe `mockImplementation`, for returning it every time you call it).

If you also want to expect the call of the fetch just add a constant:

```
const myFetch = jest.spyOn(global, 'fetch').mockImplementationOnce(
jest.fn(() => Promise.reject()) as jest.Mock);
```

You can then expect it via: `expect(myFetch).toBecalledTimes(1);`

Answer (score 0):

After one more day of researching, I might be wrong though but I don't think I have to care about token or authorization when unit testing for front-end. All I need is [jest.fn()](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestfnimplementation) to mock function and [jest.spyOn(global, "fetch")](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname) to track fetch API.

For more information, here are some references that I read:

https://codewithhugo.com/jest-fn-spyon-stub-mock/

https://dev.to/qmenoret/mocks-and-spies-with-jest-32gf

https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-does-jest.fn()-work

https://www.loupetestware.com/post/mocking-api-calls-with-jest

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello, could you please post the updated code?